# Is there a resource for English relational nouns

Tags: english, corpora, resource-request

Relational nouns, like `brother`, `mother`, `capital`, `advisor`, `leader` are different from sortal words like `cup`, `person`, or `woman`.

They differ in the sense that, one cannot decide if `x` is a `brother` unto itself, but rather must consider whether `x` is a `brother` in relation to some `y`.  On the other hand, one can decide whether `x` is a `person` just by looking at `x` -- one need not look at other objects and their relationship to `x`.

**Is there a resource listing relational nouns for english?**

Comment: Are "teacher", "butcher" or "lunch" relational nouns?

Comment: I'm not sure how sharp the boundary is, but I don't think those are examples are relational nouns.

Comment: So you're talking about nouns that require something else to establish their meaning? Like a capital *of* a country, a brother *of* someone, a leader *of* a group, and so on?

Comment: @user6726 - 'Teacher' seems to be "relational"; there must be pupils if there is a teacher. But 'butcher' and 'lunch' don't seem relational in the same sense. What would be their respective counterparts? (Though the OP does list 'leader' as "relational", so perhaps it considers 'butcher' relational too. Which brings into question, how do we define "relational"?

Comment: Well, a butcher is one in virtue of processing some meat product, and lunch is in relation to the consumer. If it's part of the meaning of "mother" that you give birth to some X, it's part of the meaning of "lunch" that someone eats you (or would eat you). So yes, it is about what "relational" means.

Comment: @user6726 for a general description of what a relational noun is see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_noun), and for more precise description for English see this [this](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P88-1004).  Here "relational" has a technical meaning that admittedly I don't totally grasp, not the more general meaning that would admit any noun as relational.  Does that help?

Comment: I think one good test is whether it really means anything to be <noun> without that thing that it implies relation to.  For example, the common sense of "friend" (as in "she is my friend") doesn't have meaning without knowing who she is the friend of.  I would argue teacher is not relational, teacher like butcher is a profession.  It describes a person with skills and a readiness or intention to offer services.  "Captain" is probably relational.  We need to know what you are a captain of (at least implicitly) before it really means anything.

Comment: @Alenanno -- precisely

Comment: This isn't necessarily a natural category, so there may not be any good way to describe it. The technical definition in the original paper is "Relational nouns are usually viewed as either requiring non-compositional semantic interpretation, or causing an undesirable proliferation of syntactic rules." In other words, they refer to anything unusual, normally an implicit reference to some other contextual variable or actor. A perfectly reasonable computational definition, but not necessarily congruent to any simple linguistic description.

Comment: @Close voter(s) Why is this question "too broad"? I could well imagine there is a concise resource in the style of WordNet or a simple list for that, and Edward Newell asked for nothing more than a list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a wordnet (e.g., [the Princeton Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)) can be used to extract some relevant nouns. The only disadvantage of the existing wordnets is their rather low coverage of the full lexicon.

But given a starting set, you can try some techniques from machine learning to find more of them in a huge corpus.